# GridView with zoom

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I'd like to implement a GridView with an option for a 2 fingers zoom. for example, if we zoom on the top left area: 
[image: GridView zoom]

I'm trying to do this with a GridView because each cell should be clickable for doing a different action.
Is there any interface I need to implement? Is it possible to get this result with an ImageView? How would you do it? Code would be appreciated.